# Security error in Firefox when using XMLSerializer

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

When using this function:

```
        function XMLToString(oXML) {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return oXML.xml;
            } else {
                return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);
            }
        }
```

Firebug throws this error:

```
Security error
    return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);
```

I am using Firefox 7.01 version.

EDIT: The XML response is from a web service on a remote domain.

Comment: What's in the XML?  Where does it come from?

Comment: @Pointy XML is valid application/xml response from a web service. When I access the web service URL in the browser, it displays XML correctly without errors.

Comment: The web service, is that on a different domain by any chance? Have a look at http://www.mrclay.org/2008/09/06/case-of-the-ns_error_dom_security_err/.

Comment: @pimvdb Yes the web service is on a different domain, is that a problem?

Comment: @pimvdb The link you posted does not apply to my problem. There are no CSS stylesheets.

Comment: I mean that there is probably a reference to another domain. It does necessarily have to be a stylesheet. Do you have control over the server of the web service?

Comment: @pimvdb No. It's a remove web service.

Comment: I meant remote web service. Typo.

Comment: Can you link to an actual page showing the behavior?  This should generally not happen....

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's

```
$.parseXML(xml)
```

and

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml);
```

see the [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467742/conversion-from-jquery-xml-object-to-string-throws-security-error)