# Conversion from jQuery XML Object to String throws Security Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

I have a XML Object generated by jQuery from the response of a REST Webservice:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:9299/foo",
    success:function(xml) {
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        // The rest of the code manipulates the structure of the XML
    }
});
```

Now I need to output the altered XML Object as a String. I've already found this solution for Firefox and other browsers:

```
out = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml);
```

But all I get here is the following error message:

```
[Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"  location: "http://localhost/bar"]
```

All files I need are on localhost (including the webservice which provides me the XML and the jQuery library)

Any ideas would be highly appreciated

**Edit:**

I've simplified the problem and tried the following code:

```
$xml = $('<?xml version="1.0"?><root><element>bla</element><element>blubb</element></root>');
$xml.find("element").each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
out = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml);
```

Even without any webservice call the problem remains the same. (The alert outputs the content correctly)

**Edit 2:**

Thanks to the comment by Kevin B, I've got a working solution:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:9299/foo",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success:function(xml) {
        var $xml = $(xml);
        // The rest of the code manipulates the structure of the XML
    }
});
```

The last line doesn't change:

```
out = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml);
```

Comment: About your latest edit. You didn't parse it as XML. http://jsfiddle.net/RKpua/7/

Comment: Your Edit2, if you set `dataType: "xml"` like in my answer, you don't need `$.parseXML()`

Answer (score 1):

First off, I can't confirm/deny based on your code whether or not this is a cross-domain request. Cross-domain is when the port number, domain, or protocol of the external file is different from the one requesting the external file.

If it is indeed a cross-domain request, you need to implement [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or a server-side proxy to request it for you.

Secondly, you don't need to use `$.parseXML()`. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/foo",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:function(xml) {
        var $xml = $(xml);
        // The rest of the code manipulates the structure of the XML
    }
});
```

The XML also must be valid for it to work in all browsers.

Edit: So, it's not a cross-domain issue, and it is not a jquery issue. Here's some more debugging: http://jsfiddle.net/RKpua/ I used a very simple xml document there, can you replace the simple xml document with your xml?

Comment: Thanks, the line containing $.parseXML() was really unnecessary. Unfortunately, it still doesnt work. As you mentioned, the port number of my Webservice actually is different from my jquery-using interface. But that shouldn't matter, because i save the data in the local variable xml and only refer to it afterwards, or am I wrong? And the rest of the required files (like the jquery library) are available on the same server (and port).

Comment: If it is cross-domain as you suggest, it is not going to be possible to request it with javascript unless you implement CORS or use a server-side proxy script to request it for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: But I have already been able to load the webservice response and alter / output different parts of its DOM (in the corresponding object). Why is this working, and the conversion from the local object to a normal String not?

Comment: You may already have CORS implemented, if you didn't it would have failed long before that.

Comment: Now I've simplified the problem - without success. (See the edit in my post)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the output because jQuery infers it. in any case you can specify the dataType.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:9299/foo",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:function(xml) {
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        // The rest of the code manipulates the structure of the XML
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the xml dom property of the jQuery object by specifying the first element in the jquery object.

```
out = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($xml[0]);
```

Also XMLSerializer is not available in IE < 9.  For IE8 use the following

```
out = $xml[0].xml;
```

Or as a jquery extension

```
$.fn.xml2string = function(){
if (window.XMLSerializer) {
    return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this[0]);
} else if (typeof this[0].xml != "undefined") {
    return this[0].xml;
}
return "";
};
```

Comment: How come the IE8 example uses the function `xml()` and the xml2string function uses the property `xml`. Shouldn't it be a property in both cases? (or a function in both cases?)

Comment: You're right.  xml is a property of the XML node in IE8. It should not have the parenthesize. Answer updated.